# Rails : How to add user inputed value to button_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm currently using Stripe Checkout and I want to add the quantity to my "Pay now" button.
I'm currently doing this

```
<%= button_to "Pay Now", checkout_create_path, params: {
        :article_id => @article.id}, remote: true %>
```

How can I add a field to my params of the button, filled by the user and add it to the `params:` field of my button ?

Like this it doesn't work :

```
    <%= number_field :quantity, :class => "form-control" %>
```

Comment: Your question is ambiguous. Can you give an example of what you are trying to accomplish? Do you want the button to display the amount the person is paying IN the button as text?

Comment: No I have a product and I want the user to be able to say he wants 5 of them, and the put the value of the quantity field to the post request

Comment: Still very unclear. Post your entire form code. You wont' get people bothering to try and answer if you put in no effort to explaining exactly what you want, what you already have, and what you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write some JS to add the parameter to the link/button, but that isn't the way to do it. Better to use a form:

```rb
<%= form_tag checkout_create_path, remote: true do %>
  <%= hidden_field :order, :article_id, value: @article.id %>
  <%= number_field :order, :quantity, :class => "form-control" %>

  <%= submit_tag "Pay Now" %>
<% end %>
```

Then your controller will have access to the following params:

```rb
{"order"=>{"article_id"=>"1", "quantity"=>"3"} ...}
```

You could also have some notion of an `Order` with the accompanying `@order` variable and use `form_for @order`.